# How to create PowerPoint office 2013 addin something similar to .ppa file

Tags: powerpoint, add-in

One the requirements in my project is to migrate existing PowerPoint 2003/2007 Add-ins (written in macro) to PowerPoint 2013. I don't find an option to save file in .ppa (office 2013 version).

I am pretty new to add-ins and macro code. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

File | Save As | Choose Save As Type:  PowerPoint 97-2003 Add-In (PPA)